# Drupal 7 Commerce module Checkout button disappearing

Tags: drupal, checkout, commerce, webshop

I am currently using Commerce module (latest version) on my Drupal 7 website as a web-shop solution.

After installing and configuring all the necessary modules (Commerce, Commerce Shipping, Product, PayPal module etc.), I faced with an issue that the "Checkout" button disappeared after a while (approx. 10 hours) from the Cart menu.

To fix it, I did not have to do anything except clearing the cache, but after ~10 hours the problem came back, and so far it happened several times.

Is there anybody who has any idea what cause this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for this issues are:

1.Wrong configuration of Drupal cache modules like APC, Memcache or Boost module

2.Some Rules are triggered automatically

To resolve this issue you may perform below steps.

1. Disable all cache related modules
2. If you are using Boost module then disable it and uninstall it.
3. Check drupal dblog entries

If problem persist please share your server environment details like Drupal version, commerce module version, php version and server OS